# Replacing dots in a filename

Tags: php, replace, filenames

How should I replace dots with underlines without losing the file extension?

```
$str = $_FILES['files']['name']; //file.name.word.jpg
$ext = end(explode('.', $str));
$filename = explode('.', $str);
//output file_name_word.jpg
```

ps: it needs to be before upload.. if the user uploads a file with dots it must to be renamed and inserted on db

Comment: Check here http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/pathinfo) to extract the file name and  [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) to remove all the dots out of it.

```
$filename = pathinfo('/path/to/your/file');
echo str_replace('.', '_', $filename['filename']);
```

Comment: this will replace last dot also

Comment: complete: `str_replace('.', '_', $filename['filename']).".".$filename['extension'];`

Comment: @vladkras: No, it won't. Only the filename is extracted. See the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "file.name.word.jpg";
$regex = "/(\.)(?=\S+\.)/";
echo preg_replace($regex, "_", $str);
```

short form

```
echo preg_replace("/(\.)(?=\S+\.)/", "_", "file.name.word.jpg");
```

Comment: avoid regex when native functions available

Comment: pathinfo() and this complex one if you like: `$result = str_replace(".", "_", substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, ".")) ).".".end(explode('.',$str));`

Comment: @vladkras: native functions: [pathinfo()](http://php.net/pathinfo) and [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace). See the usage [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17689501/1438393)

Comment: you use: 1. `pathinfo()` 2. create new var `$filename` 3. `str_replace` 4. creating new var with `_` 5. concat file name and extension I use 1! string and 1! function

Comment: Just a note: if the extension is `.tar.gz`, the filename would be `file_name_word_tar.gz` which I don't think is what the op wants.

Comment: @AmalMurali are you sure his script is made for uploading both images and tarballs? if he is creating kinda file storage, he has to use more protection, like filesize, filetype, etc. not just replacing dots with underlines

Comment: That was a nitpick really. But it boils down to what @Akam said: **why use regex when built-in functions are available**?

Comment: `preg_replace` is not built-in? [really](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)?