# How do I rename a php image that has a period (.) in the name

Tags: php, rename

Im trying to rename an image that has a full stop in the name with php using the `rename()` function.

`rename("images/cat.cute.jpg", "images/cute-cat.jpg");`

Currently getting a "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: The dot in the filename should not matter.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689465/replacing-dots-in-a-filename Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `images/cat.cute.jpg`, you are specifying a path *relative* to wherever your PHP script is actually executing.  The error you are getting is simply telling you that there is no file called `cat.cute.jpg` in the folder `images` relative to the execution location of the script.  Or, such a folder `images` does not exist.  To fix this, you either need to specify the correct relative path, or you may specify an absolute path.  Here is an example of using `rename()` with absolute paths:

```
rename("/images/cat.cute.jpg", "/images/cute-cat.jpg");
```

This assumes that there is an `images/` folder relative to root, which may not be the case, but you can adjust as you need.